# Kendo Ui inline popup width

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

Ok So i am using kendo ui excellent peice of kit btw for my data grid I have created an eidtor template for my inline popup.

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                    .Name("datepicker")
)
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<FuelActivityTrackerDal.Models.ActivityHeader>()
                        .Name("grid")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Filterable(false);
                            columns.Bound(p => p.Description);
                            columns.Bound(p => p.ActivityDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                            columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeName);
                            columns.Bound(p => p.Status);
                            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(160);

                        })
                           .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("ActivityEditor")).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })


                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .Scrollable()
                    .Filterable()
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .PageSize(Model.Count())
                        .Read(read => read.Action("Activity_Read", "Activity"))
                    )
)
```

And I have here my activity template but my question is how does one make the popup width bigger and can you use bootstrap columns in the template?.

I tried using .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" }) on the popup but it doesnt seem to adjust it.

```
@model FuelActivityTrackerDal.Models.ActivityHeader

<div class="k-edit-form-container">
    <h3>Activity</h3>
    <br />
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)

    <div class="k-edit-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>


    <div class="k-edit-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActivityDate)
    </div>
    <div class="k-edit-field">
        @Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.ActivityDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActivityDate)
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a dojo I prepared using some code I actually use to resize the popup window.

https://dojo.telerik.com/UNiHehes

although you are using the MVC wrappers you just need to bind to the editEvent like

```
.events(eve => eve.Edit('resizeMode'))
```

(from memory)

Then this is the code that does the resizing for you:

```
    function resizeMode() {
     var popUpWindow = $(".k-popup-edit-form").data("kendoWindow");
     var contentArea = $(".k-edit-form-container");
     var innerForm = $(".k-edit-form-container"); //add your class for you form in here.
     contentArea.height($(window).innerHeight() * 0.8).width($(window).innerWidth() * 0.8);


     var fixedHeight = (contentArea.height() - 70);
     var fixedWidth = contentArea.width() * 0.80;
     console.log($(window).innerWidth());
     innerForm.height(fixedHeight).width(fixedWidth).css({

       maxHeight: fixedHeight + 'px !important',

       maxWidth: fixedWidth + 'px !important',


       overflowY: 'scroll',
       overflowX: 'hidden'

     });
     popUpWindow.center();
   }
```

So what I usually like to do is make the popup window scrollable but ensure that the update/cancel button are on the screen at all time (i.e. fixed to the bottom of the window). 
So I have added some additional code into the resizing function to ensure that the update button section is `pinned` to the bottom of the form. If the popup controls are not surrounded by an additional div/class then it will just pin them to the bottom of the `form`

So let me explain what this code is doing:

First we get the popup window instance via the class name (this could also be done via the data-role if you wanted to as well. 
Secondly we then get the pop up window content area (so everything below the form title)
Thirdly we get the actual div with the form in it.

Once we have these components we can then resize how we want. So in my example I am doing this based on the `window` of the browser but you could do it on something else if you wanted? 
In my example I am then resizing the window to take up 80% of the screen real estate again you could change this on your needs.

Now we have resized the pop up window we need to make sure the form takes up the appropriate amount of space and doesn't overflow the window which is why I am setting it to take up 70% of the available height (as this takes into account of pinning the update/cancel buttons) and then 80%  of the width again this could go as far as 99% if you wanted (I never set this to 100% width of the new window size to take into account of the scroll bar)

Then finally we set the max height and width css attributes and then call the center function on the window so it center's it nicely for us.